# Download docx file created in Flask using VueJS

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask

I'm trying to figure out how to download a docx file in VueJS. I initially tried to create it in the frontend but the file ends up being corrupt so I'm using flask to create the docx file (which when I save locally opens just fine) and then sending it over to the frontend where I want to download it but the file ends up being corrupted.

For the Flask API this is what I use to create the file:

```
def download_docx():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        write_to_docx = data.get('docxData')
        document = Document()
        new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
        new_parser.add_html_to_document(write_to_docx, document)
        docx_file = BytesIO()
        file_name = "test.docx"
        document.save(docx_file)
        docx_file.seek(0)
        return send_file(docx_file,
                             attachment_filename=file_name,
                             as_attachment=True,
                             mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                             cache_timeout=0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.print_exc())
    return render_template('index.html')
```

For the VueJS side I have:

```
export function downloadDocx(token, data) {
  const headers = authHeader(token)
  return mainAxios.post(`${API_URL}/download/docx`, data, { headers })
}



downloadDocx() {
      
      let data = {
        docxData: this.fullHtml
      }
      this.$store.dispatch('downloadDocx', data)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data && response.status == 200) {
          const blob = new Blob([ response.data ], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' })
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var element = document.createElement('a');
          element.setAttribute('href', url);
          element.setAttribute('download', 'test.docx');
          element.style.display = 'none';
          document.body.appendChild(element);
          element.click();
          document.body.removeChild(element);
        }
        else {
          console.log("FAILED")
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see if it works.

```
downloadDocx() {
    let data = { docxData: this.fullHtml }
    this.$store.dispatch('downloadDocx', data)
        .then((resp) => (resp.status === 200 ? resp.blob() : Promise.reject('something went wrong')))
        .then((blob) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            const a = document.createElement('a')
            a.setAttribute('download', "true")
            a.style.display = 'none'
            a.href = url
            a.download = 'test.docx'
            document.body.appendChild(a)
            a.click()
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
        })
        .catch(() => alert('Cannot download the file'))
}
```

Another option is to use `FileSaver.js` (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

Comment: Is there a way to create a "url" for the file I create on flask and send that over to download directly instead of sending the file information as a blob?

Comment: Yes if you just want to provide a link that will trigger download then you can certainly do that in Python as well just set the header `headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="text.xlsx"'` that should get the job done.